# Expiration date for a row

Tags: matrix, date, expire

I have a new problem that I can't resolve yet. I want to set an expiration date in the matrix for each row. I have a column "date" that I need to use as an expiration date. In search I don't want to display the row if is expired, and if its the only row, I want to ignore it in results.

It is posible to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Inside your Matrix tag pair this will work:

```
{if expiration_date_column > current_time}
    {!-- not expired yet, put your row html here --}
{/if}
```

Or you can use the search parameter on the Matrix opening tag. This is probably better if you only want your result set to include unexpired rows:

```
{your_matrix_field search:expiration_date_column=">{current_time}"}
    {!-- this returns only unexpired rows --}
{/your_matrix_field}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was going to suggest.